# Smith normal form and group representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, abelian-groups, smith-normal-form

Suppose you are given a finite abelian group $G$ represented by a (square) matrix $M$, that is $$G \cong \mathbb{Z}^n /M \cong \mathbb{Z}^n /S, $$ where $S$ is the Smith normal form of $M$.

My question is, given an element $v$ of $G$ written as a vector $v \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ (seen as a vector in the cokernel of $M$), how can it be transformed in a vector $v'\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ in the cokernel of $S$?

Comment: I am not sure why the tags/title has been changed, this question does not concern representation theory, but the presentation of a group.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $\mathbb{Z}^n /M$ ? Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}^n /{\mathsf{Ker}}(M)$ ?

Comment: No, sorry for the unclear notation, this is the cokernel of $M$, that is $\mathbb{Z}^n / M \mathbb{Z}^n$, so the image of $M$ and not its kernel.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is still unclear. How do you "write an element of $G$" (which is a quotient) as a vector $v\in{\mathbb Z}^n$ ? If you "write" the quotient element $v+M{\mathbb Z}^n$ as simply $v$, then $v'=v$ and your question makes no sense. Perhaps your intended meaning is really about the isomorphism between the two quotients ${\mathbb Z}^n/M$ and ${\mathbb Z}^n/S$.

Comment: I guess that is a matter of terminology, i apologise if it is still unclear. Suppose the group is $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, presented by the $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ with column vectors $v_1 = (1,1)^T$ and $v_2 = (-1,1)^T$; then $S = Diag(1,2)$. Then $v_1$ is the trivial element in  $G$ presented by $M$, but not if seen in $G$ when presented by $S$. What I need is an algorithm that relates elements between the two presentations, so I guess you are right in your comment.

Comment: When you day "a vector in the cokernel of $M$", you need to realize that the elements in the cokernel of $M$ are cosets and that they have no natural representation as a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformation you're looking for is simply $v'=Pv$, where
$PMQ=S$ is the Smith decomposition of $S$ : $P,Q$ are invertible and $S$ is diagonal with each diagonal coefficient dividing the next.

Let $g\in G$. If we present $G$ as $\frac{{\mathbb Z}^n}{M{\mathbb Z}^n}$, we see that $g$ is represented by a coset $m=v+M{\mathbb Z}^n$ for some $v\in {\mathbb Z}^n$. Then :

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
m &=& v+M{\mathbb Z}^n \\
  &=& v+P^{-1}SQ^{-1}{\mathbb Z}^n \\
  &=& v+P^{-1}S{\mathbb Z}^n \ (\textrm{because}\ Q \ \textrm{is  invertible}) \\
  &=& P^{-1}Pv+P^{-1}S{\mathbb Z}^n \\
  &=& P^{-1}(Pv+S{\mathbb Z}^n) \\
  &=& P^{-1}(v'+S{\mathbb Z}^n) \\
\end{array}
$$

Note that the two cosets, $v+M{\mathbb Z}^n$ and $v'+S{\mathbb Z}^n$ are not equal but they are related by the isomorphism $P^{-1}$.